# How to decrease colorbar WIDTH in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have a plot I made in ipython notebook using two imported datasets & an array I made for the x-axis, but the colorbar is a bit thick for my liking. Is there any way to make it slimmer?

```
#import packages
import numpy as np              #for importing u array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #for plotting
%matplotlib inline

th = np.loadtxt("MT3_th.dat") #imports data file- theta pert.
pi = np.loadtxt("MT3_pi.dat") #imports data file- pressure pert.
k  = np.loadtxt("MT3_z.dat")  #imports data file- height
i = np.linspace(-16.,16.,81)  #x-axis array
x, z = np.meshgrid(i, k)

th[th == 0.0] = np.nan #makes zero values for th white
clevels = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3.]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
thplot = plt.contourf(x, z, th, clevels, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, vmin=0., vmax=3.)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
piplot = ax2.contour(x, z, pi, 6, colors='k')

plt.axis([-16.,16, 0, 16.])
plt.xticks(np.arange(-16,16.001,4))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,16.001,2))
plt.colorbar(pad=0.05, orientation="horizontal")
plt.xlabel("x (km)", size=15)
plt.ylabel("z (km)", size=15)
plt.title("Initial temp. & pres. perturbations (K, Pa)", size=20)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Looking for the same answer I think I found something easier to work with compatible with the current version of Matplotlib to decrease the width of the colorbar. One can use the "ratio" option of the matplolib.figure function (see http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html). And here is an example :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# generate data 

x = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0.1, 0.5, 1000)


hist = plt.hist2d(x,y, bins=100)

plt.colorbar(aspect=20)
plt.colorbar(aspect=50)
```

[image]

Comment: For people looking to widen the color bar, this can also be done using aspect. For me, aspect=12 looked good.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to manually fix it using add_axes. (Thank goodness for colleagues!)

```
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.09, 0.06, 0.84, 0.02])
fig.colorbar(thplot, cax=cbar_ax, orientation="horizontal")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a combination of `fraction` and `aspect` parameters to get the desired width of the colorbar while it still stretched across the plot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).